# ListView Group Headers Showing Multiple Times

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, grouping

I have a ListView with groups and group headers which I've written based on a certain [WPF tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/).

This functions properly, but if I close the window it's in and reopen it by recreating it (making a new instance), then all the headers get duplicated.
I.e. rather than having "My Header" and the items under it, I have "My Header", another "My Header" under it, and the items are under that one.
Reopening it at that point adds a third header.
If I switch to a different items source, the same thing happens there, and it seems to remember how many repetitions each source has.

Note that I make absolutely no change to the contents of the source collection at any point. Serializing it during the various stages yields the exact same file. To being with, the headers are created just from a string value in the data; I don't even know how that could cause any recursion, yet clearly it does.

If instead of recreating the window I reuse it and update the binding upon showing it, this problem no longer occurs, but conversely, opening the window with a different items source now shows the items without group headers at all.

I have tried looking up any similar issue but to no avail, and I'm new to WPF so I'm not yet versed in its workings.

Here are screenshots of the window in both states, along with the visual tree and the headers in it:

[image: First time opening the window, only one header]

[image: Second time opening the window, duplicated header]

I did find [this seemingly not-that-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878500/listview-grouping-does-not-update-when-bound-property-is-changed) and subsequently tried using a `CollectionViewSource` but I couldn't get that to work right either - the super group it showed behaved properly, but under it the exact same phenomena occurred.

Here is the XAML code for the ListView:

```xaml
<ListView
    x:Name="lvComponents" Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ScriptComponents}"
    SelectionChanged="LvComponents_SelectionChanged"
    lvl:ListViewLayoutManager.Enabled ="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    externals:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"
    externals:GridViewSort.SortGlyphAscending="/Resources/Program Icons/Sort Up.png"
    externals:GridViewSort.SortGlyphDescending="/Resources/Program Icons/Sort Down.png">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn lvl:FixedColumn.Width="36">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ComponentToIconPathConverter}}" Width="32"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" lvl:ProportionalColumn.Width="1" externals:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ctl:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" lvl:ProportionalColumn.Width="1" externals:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Type">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True" x:Name="xpComponents">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource StringToProgramIconPathConverter}}" Width="16" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" (" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=")" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Any ideas for the cause of this, or even for a workaround, would be greatly appreciated.

It would be even better if I could reuse the window rather than recreate it (what now causes the headers to not show up at all when changing sources), but I'll take what I can get.

Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution . If I use

```
List<User> itemssss = new List<User>();
 if (lvUsers.ItemsSource != null)
    itemssss = (List<User>)lvUsers.ItemsSource;
items.Add(new User() { Name = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(), Age = 42, Sex = "Male" });
lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Sex");
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

Then Header show multiple times. but if I use

```
    List<User> itemssss = new List<User>();
    if (lvUsers.ItemsSource != null)
        itemssss = (List<User>)lvUsers.ItemsSource;

    List<User> items = new List<User>();
    foreach (var item in itemssss)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }
    items.Add(new User() { Name = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(), Age = 42, Sex = "Male" });
    lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Sex");
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

it works fine for me